# How to get rows repeating as per selected data set in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have a CTE Query but I have nothing concepts about it. And I am new in programming. Actually i have Qty column in my query and i want repeat rows until qty. means if qty is equal to 50 then data set returns me 50 time records. if qty is equal to 1000 thousand then query returns me 10000 thousand records. Following query works fine for me till <99 rcords how can i grow for 1000 rocords.

Thanx in advance.

```
SELECT * INTO #TableA
FROM
(

SELECT MIS_Request_Detail.vno, MIS_Request_Detail.IID
       , MIS_Request_Detail.Qty-MIS_Request_Detail.BalQty qty, 
       1 RcvdQty, pk,
       ItmMstr.IName, ItmMstr.UName, '' SrNo,
       MIS_Request_Detail.Qty As ReqQty, MIS_Request_Detail.BalQty
       , MIS_Request_Detail.Qty-MIS_Request_Detail.BalQty RemainQty
FROM MIS_Request_Detail INNER JOIN
view_MIS_Item_Master ItmMstr ON ItmMstr.IID=MIS_Request_Detail.IID
WHERE ReqType=1 AND MIS_Request_Detail.vno=@vno 

) T
;WITH Nbrs ( Number ) AS (
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 + Number FROM Nbrs WHERE Number < 99 
)

SELECT A.vno,A.IID, A.IName, A.UName, CAST(SrNo AS VARCHAR(50)) SrNo
   , CAST(N.Number AS varchar(50)) QTY, pk ReqDetpk, RcvdQty,
   A.ReqQty, A.BalQty, A.RemainQty, 0 Color,  0 chked, 0 Pk, 0 AS isupdate
   , '' AS isdeleted
FROM #TableA A
JOIN Nbrs N ON N.Number <= A.qty
ORDER BY IID, N.Number, pk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably discovered, the recursion limit is 99 for recursive CTE's. To get around this, you have to use a series of CROSS JOINs, as found in the [SQL Magazine article by Itzik Ben-Gan](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-of-numbers).

```
WITH
L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
SELECT n FROM Nums
```

This gives you numbers all the way up to 4 billion.

Answer (score 0):

In #TableA I add Id on case if your temporary table doesn't contain identifier and number of rows more than 1

```
SELECT * INTO #TableA
FROM
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id,
        MIS_Request_Detail.vno, MIS_Request_Detail.IID
        , MIS_Request_Detail.Qty-MIS_Request_Detail.BalQty qty, 
        1 RcvdQty, pk,
        ItmMstr.IName, ItmMstr.UName, '' SrNo,
        MIS_Request_Detail.Qty As ReqQty, MIS_Request_Detail.BalQty
        , MIS_Request_Detail.Qty-MIS_Request_Detail.BalQty RemainQty
FROM MIS_Request_Detail INNER JOIN
  view_MIS_Item_Master ItmMstr ON ItmMstr.IID=MIS_Request_Detail.IID
WHERE ReqType=1 AND MIS_Request_Detail.vno=@vno 
) T

;WITH Nbrs(Id, vno, IID, IName, UName, SrNo, QTY, ReqDetpk, RcvdQty, ReqQty, 
           BalQty, RemainQty, Color, chked, Pk, isupdate, isdeleted, [Level]) AS (
SELECT A.Id, A.vno,A.IID, A.IName, A.UName, CAST(SrNo AS VARCHAR(50)) SrNo
       , CAST(N.Number AS varchar(50)) QTY, pk ReqDetpk, RcvdQty,
       A.ReqQty, A.BalQty, A.RemainQty, 0 Color,  0 chked, 0 Pk, 0 AS isupdate
       , '' AS isdeleted, 1 AS [Level]
FROM #TableA A
UNION ALL
SELECT A.Id, A.vno,A.IID, A.IName, A.UName, CAST(SrNo AS VARCHAR(50)) SrNo
       , CAST(N.Number AS varchar(50)) QTY, pk ReqDetpk, RcvdQty,
       A.ReqQty, A.BalQty, A.RemainQty, 0 Color,  0 chked, 0 Pk, 0 AS isupdate
       , '' AS isdeleted, n.[Level] + 1
FROM #TableA A JOIN Nbrs n ON A.Id = n.Id
WHERE A.Number > n.[Level]
)
SELECT *
FROM Nbrs
ORDER BY IID, N.Number, pk
```